# When I run several threads that match the number of CPU core/threads, will each thread run on a separate core/thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

The threads are launched by `std::async(func)`.

If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard does not guarantee anything about on what cores/hyperthreads your threads will run. That is up to the operating system.

If you want to get platform specific (non-portable) then there are various API's to control thread affinity - like (for example) [pthread_setaffinity_np](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) on Linux.
But I'd personally advice just leaving it to the OS - it will most likely do a good job unless you have *very* specific needs.

Comment: You can only leave the choice of cores to OS if you do not really care about performance.

Comment: I agree and I disagree. In my experience, the OS will do the sensible/right thing most of the time and you don't need to worry about it (besides, that's what the OS is there *for* - right?). In most cases when people try to outsmart the OS they actually end up making things worse. In a few *rare* cases people have real reasons to overrule the os *and* are competent enough to do it right and can get a performance improvement by doing so. But that is a really *rare* case in my experience. So by default; just leave it to the OS.

Comment: The problem is that OSes love to shuffle things around when they believe it to be for the greater good. As a result, thread is evicted to another CPU, and all caches are invalidated. So you are just experiencing random and hard to explain delay in your application. Nasty surprise. That's why in my line of work units of execution are always bound to cores.

Answer (score 4):

In complement to Jesper's answer, the standard offers you the function [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency/) to get the number of hardware thread contexts (0 if information not available).

The way the threads are schedules is implementation dependent.  You can however be sure that your code has to share the cores with dozen of OS processes/services/daemons running with their own threads.

In view of your question, as you mention [`std::async(func)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/), it's worth to mention that you could force a launch policy, for example `launch::async`. Some implementations offer finer control, but again, the scheduling is implementation dependent.